# whoever or whomever HELP!

Tags: whoever-vs-whomever

Please help: **whoever** or **whomever**?

And this is the sentence, it cannot be changed!

I think **whomever** is correct—because isn't the answer to the **he**/**him** test **him**? As in **Who are we free to pretend to be?** Is the answer **he** or **him**? It is **him**, right? We are free to pretend to be **him**... not **he**...

**Each of us is freer than ever to believe whatever and pretend to be *whoever*/*whomever* we wish.**

Thank you!!!

<3